# Generating a random number that can be accesed anywhere

Tags: c#, random

Here is the beginning of my code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static Random random = new Random();
    int prevnum;
    int currentnum;

    public int GenerateRandomNumber()
    {
        return random.Next(1, 1000);
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 1000);
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void enterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentnum = Convert.ToInt32(guessBox.Text);

        if (randomNumber < currentnum)
        {
            warmOrColdLabel.Text = "Too High";

            if (currentnum > prevnum)
            {
                guessBox.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                prevnum = currentnum;
            }
            else
            {
                guessBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
                prevnum = currentnum;
            }
        }
        if (randomNumber > currentnum)
        {
            warmOrColdLabel.Text = "Too Low";

            if (currentnum > prevnum)
            {
                guessBox.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                prevnum = currentnum;
            }
            else
            {
                guessBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
                prevnum = currentnum;
            }
        }
        if (randomNumber == currentnum)
        {
            guessBox.Enabled = false;
            enterButton.Enabled = false;
            playAgainButton.Enabled = true;
        }

    }

    private void playAgainButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        enterButton.Enabled = true;
        guessBox.Enabled = true;
        playAgainButton.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

The issue I have is getting a random number, it always puts out 0. I simply need a random number that I can put into different buttons and such. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: must be a random number between 1 and 1000.

Comment: It seems that the bottom part of you code got cut out. Could you please put it back in?

Comment: The argument in the Random constructor does not signify the max value, but it's for the random seed. Just leave the constructor blank.

Comment: Also, you can use `random.Next( 1, 1000 );` to create a random number from 1 to 1000. Look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Comment: I went ahead and put in all my code.

Answer (score 6):

You don't actually call `RandomNumberHandler()` anywhere.  Also, you need to specify your range in the call to `.Next()` (e.g., `random.Next(1000)+1` to get a number from 1 to 1000).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  //other stuff from before
  int randomNumber; //move this here

 public Form1()
 {
    randomNumber = random.Next(1, 1000);  //assign it here
    InitializeComponent();

 }
```

Comment: But I want the random number to be defined outside the button, I don't want to call the random number inside it. Would this affect it?

Comment: Then call the `RandomNumberHandler` method in the Form1 constructor.

Comment: It's saying something like " cannont convert method group 'GenerateRandomNumber' to non-delgate type int

Comment: @Nogg: add the line `randomNumber = random.Next(1, 1001);` to the constructor, just after the line that reads `InitializeComponent();` That will generate the random number. The reason it's always 0 right now is, as @jonsca pointed out, because you never call `random.next()`.

Comment: @Nogg, it may have to be static, but try what Jim is suggesting first.

Comment: Go ahead and look at my updated code, I put everything in there now. It just doesn't seem to work >.<

Comment: @Nogg randomNumber is temporary to the constructor.  Declare it where you had it before, while still calling random.Next in the constructor.

Comment: I'm lost, which part are you talking about? Declare which where? Do I even need the GenerateRandomNumber() method? It looks like I don't even use it.

Comment: @Nogg see my code addition.  If you declare an int within a method like you did, when the method completes the int is destroyed

Comment: @Nogg: if @jonsca's response answered your question, you should accept it as the answer (click the check mark).

Answer (score 1):

Main problem is randomNumber is initialized when the constructor is called, and thereafter when you access it you access the same value.

You should eliminate that instance variable, and instead simply make a new call to GenerateRandom().

In addition, you probably want to make your instance of Random a static variable:

```
static Random random =
```

Otherwise each time the class is unloaded and reloaded it will repeat the same sequence which would be less random (or rather, pseudo random).